# Prevent someone to login to my website from teamviewer

Tags: authentication

I have my own suspicions that there are blocked users of my website that use Teamviewer to login to my site from their friends' pc. Is there any way to identify if the one who visit a website is using the Teamviewer at the same time?

Comment: How do you block users? You say they login to your site using another PC - so you block IP addresses? Maybe you could implement some account verification after registration. You could also log users logging in from the same IP address to track down those using same PC/proxy (not reliable solution, but it could give you some insight).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

Teamviewer is a Program which "control" the other PC. To find out if Teamviwer is running on a PC you must have access to the Computer, physically or with a remote control program like Teamviewer or Remote Desktop.

Comment: i removed this because this dont really answer the question. I mean there that it should be possible when you sniffing the Network of the PC on which TV is running, it can be possible that the Network Packages for TV can be identify as them and someone can check if a PC has TV running if he do this.